# Graceful shutdown of windows service on server reboot

Tags: windows, azure

Is there a way to let a windows service - Tomcat in my case - gracefully shutdown when the machine or VM shuts down?

I have a schedule on a VM to shut down every night and it just kills the Tomcat process, resulting in a lot of session errors on my client.

On a graceful shutdown the clients are properly exited by the software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schedule a task in windows to shutdown your service first then shutdown your server.

You can just make a batch file the schedule it as a task

```
net stop <service name>
 shutdown /s
```